# What is the difference between [routerLink] and this.route.navigate() method in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and using Angular8.

When I make route setting for a project, I am very confused of how route works using just

[routerLink] inside of template and this.route.navigate() in .ts file.

Example

```
// just routerLink
<div [routerLink]="/blog/32"></div>


// this.router.navigate()

// blog.html
<div (click)="moveToBlog(id)"></div>
// blog.ts
  public moveToBlog(id) {
    if (id) {
      const translatedPath= `/blog/${id}`;
      this.router.navigate([translatedPath]);
    }
  }
//
```

How they work differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `[routerLink]` and `route.navigate()` navigates the same way, but `[routerLink]` directive is more suitable and easier to use in templates. While `route.navigate()` approach requires you to add `Router` dependency to your component, add `(click)` listener to an element and manually trigger a navigation when the button is clicked, `[routerLink]` asks you only the link.

Another thing to consider is that `<a>` html elements are more preferable to use if a click only triggers a navigation. If a user hovers over an `<a [routerLink]="'/blog/32'">` element on the page, browser shows the url to the user. There is also a different right-click menu for `<a>` elements which allows to copy the url for example. `<a>` elements can be clicked by middle mouse button, at least in some browsers such click opens the url in a new tab.